# Can I NOT use requirejs in marionette/backbone?

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, marionette

People mention requirejs together with marionette, backbonejs and the like.

requirejs seems an asset loader -- executing your rules on when to load what.

I know the first 'page' of my single-page-app already needs most of the files.   If I don't mind loading all files in one go, can I simply ignore requirejs?

Comment: I want to avoid requirejs so as not to learn too many new things at the same time.

Comment: Of course you can, but this will be a big mistake in case you will use BB and Marionette in big project

Comment: Sure. You can use Marionette with RequireJS, Browserify or good old fashioned `<script>`. The real advantage of requirejs/commonjs et all is, IMO, componentisation, not optimisation of script loading. You should probably use a build process with concatentation/minification whichever route you choose.

Comment: agree with @joews, also i'd like to mark one, i think most important, advantage - dependency resolving. Very soon you will have tones of files with nested deps, parent view need child, child need models, jq plugins and so on. Without RequireJS you will have to place all files by `<script>` manually, and also in proper order

Comment: I am uncertain with this: requirejs and marionette module, I should use only one but not both?

Answer (score 1):

Technically yes. Only dependencies for marionette-backbone are

- jQuery v1.8+
- Underscore v1.4.4 - 1.6.0
- Backbone v1.0.0 - 1.1.2 are preferred
- Backbone.Wreqr (Comes automatically with the bundled build)
- Backbone.BabySitter(Comes automatically with the bundled build)

Further require.js can manage use code structure in a manner which give your code much resource efficient code at the end. From my point of view for simple application which you need simple set of views,models and collection with manageable amount of code it ok to proceed without require.js.

- But if your application have complex logic and higher number of resources it's good to go require.js. Because it not good to send 15+  like individual resource requests server at very beginning of your application load. Require can make any number of your resource in to one server resource. That's the advantage. 
  What I prefer is one request of all css, one for all js, one for sprite image for graphic if things are big to handle which allow to create fast performing application.
- Take you decision looking at the amount of resources of the project. It's not essential have require.js form the beginning of your application development.

Comment: Please feel free go with minimal things later you can do all the re-factoring once you bootstrap the basic application with a minimum code effort.